# Are there any guidelines for proper use of "creative" capitalization within in a technical report?

Tags: writing-style, capitalization, tech-writing

I am trying to edit a report that seems to have a lot of common nouns capitalized. My job is to edit for consistency of this style, which I am not familiar with. Does anyone have experience with what I can only think to call "creative" capitalization rules in a business/finance setting? Here are some examples:

...our company is actively trying to reduce General & Administrative costs, participation has been the most prevalent in Asset Management and Investor Relations, compensation for Executive Management is rising YOY...etc.

Comment: It would seem that the nouns related to the company's specific business matters and activities, or whatever passes for those at that company, are capitalized. Thus, "Executive Management" is one such matter, while compensation is not; Asset Management is, but participation is not. Pretty disgusting, I know.

Comment: There is a difference between the common nouns *general and administrative* and the proper noun *General and Administrative* (which may be the name of a department). For clarity, you could use *costs of the General and Administrative department*, for instance. But, really, you should query the author to determine exactly what they mean. If both the common noun and the proper noun *mean* the same thing—it would generally be more stylistically acceptable to use the common noun in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SuziLmrdo no; there are no general rules for that.

If your company/employer/publisher/whoever has a set of house rules you should follow those rules…

If not you must make up your own rules, which for your own safety if nothing less, will prolly mean asking someone senior to confirm every decision, however boring that gets.

For a silly example, “should we use lamp-post or lamppost or what, please?"

For your own protection you need to keep asking until the seniors get bored and tell you to make your own decisions, at which point record what they said and even then ask for clarification… “Are you saying it’s up to me?”

That safely recorded, follow whatever style guide suits you.